# I do not understand why it is not Printing matrix as required in C#

Tags: c#, matrix

Scenario: Tom went to participate in a competition. The task given to him is to draw a pattern as specified below. Prompt the user to enter a number and  Display the pattern.

[image]

Important : Keep all the method as ‘Public’ and ‘Static’

Requirement :

Display a matrix

1. The diagonal of the matrix fills with  0
2. The lower triangular side is filled with  -1
3. The upper triangular side is filled with 1

Sample Input/Output

Sample Input : 1

```
Enter  a  number:

3

Sample Output :

0       1       1

-1      0       1

-1      -1      0
```

Sample Input 2:

```
Enter a number

4

Sample Output :

0       1       1       1

-1      0       1       1

-1      -1      0       1

-1      -1      -1      0
```

Here is the quote below that I am executing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace C_SHARP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                         Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
                         int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                         int[,] arr1 = new int[n,n];
                         GetArray(n);
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("\n");
                            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                            {
                                Console.Write("{0}\t", arr1[i, j]);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Write("\n\n");
        }
    
            
        public static int[,] GetArray(int num)
        {
            int i, j;
            int[,] arr1 = new int[num, num];
            for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
            { 
                for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
                {
                    if (i < j)
                    {
                        arr1[i,j]=1;
                    }
                    else if (i > j)
                    {
                        arr1[i, j] = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr1[i, j] = 0;
                    }

                }
                
            }   
            return arr1;
        }

    }
}
```

On executing this program, it prints all the rows and columns 0.
Please help me to print the matrix of required description.

Comment: You have forgotton to assign the return value of `GetArray()` to arr1. Therefore, all cells of arra1 remain at 0.

Comment: oh! 
arr1=GetArray(n); now this is working fine , Thank you so much for the help sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you return the array, but don't assign it to anything, try:

```
var arr1 = GetArray(n);
```

instead of:

```
int[,] arr1 = new int[n,n];
GetArray(n);
```